How to create index on several ORDER BY conditions?
On postgresql@12 I have a table with 300 millions rows and first query executes < 1s, but the second is 2 minutes. Why? I created all possible indexes.
First query (< 1s):
SELECT hash FROM _transfers
WHERE (from_='abcd' or to_='abcd') and blockNumber<=12345
ORDER BY blockNumber DESC
LIMIT 1000;

Second query (2 mins):
SELECT hash FROM _transfers
WHERE (from_='abcd' or to_='abcd') and blockNumber<=12345
ORDER BY blockNumber DESC, transactionIndex ASC
LIMIT 1000;

Indexes:
create index on _transfers(from_);
create index on _transfers(to_);
create index on _transfers(blockNumber);
create index on _transfers(from_, to_, blockNumber);
create index on _transfers(transactionIndex);
create index on _transfers(blockNumber, transactionIndex);
create index on _transfers(from_, to_, blockNumber, transactionIndex);
create index on _transfers(from_, to_) include(blockNumber, transactionIndex);

wallet_hunter=# EXPLAIN SELECT transactionHash
FROM _transfers
WHERE (from_='0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad' or to_='0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad') and blockNumber<=19985646
ORDER BY blockNumber DESC
LIMIT 1000;


QUERY PLAN
.---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..531.27 rows=1000 width=71)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using _transfers_blocknumber_idx on _transfers  (cost=0.57..18841537.31 rows=35503334 width=71)
         Index Cond: (blocknumber <= 19985646)
         Filter: (((from_)::text = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad'::text) OR ((to_)::text = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad'::text))
(4 rows)

wallet_hunter=# EXPLAIN SELECT transactionHash
FROM _transfers
WHERE (from_='0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad' or to_='0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad') and blockNumber<=19985646
ORDER BY blockNumber DESC, transactionIndex ASC
LIMIT 1000;


QUERY PLAN
.---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=11241022.67..11241147.06 rows=1000 width=75)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=11241022.67..15657190.85 rows=35503335 width=75)
         Workers Planned: 9
         ->  Sort  (cost=11240022.51..11249884.54 rows=3944815 width=75)
               Sort Key: blocknumber DESC, transactionindex
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on _transfers  (cost=0.00..11023732.55 rows=3944815 width=75)
                     Filter: ((blocknumber <= 19985646) AND (((from_)::text = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad'::text) OR ((to_)::text = '0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad'::text)))
 JIT:
   Functions: 5
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(10 rows)


Please update your question with the detailed EXPLAIN PLANs for both queries


In psql before you run the second query do SET jit = off and then do EXPLAIN ANALYZE the query. 2) Creating indexes on all combinations of columns is probably causing more issues then it is solving. Indexes are not magic, they are overhead.


You'll likely need to make an index that specifies the direction, ascending or descending, on each column to match your query.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html

this solved my problem create index on _transfers(blockNumber desc, transactionIndex asc);

With a query like this, you can create indexes to support the WHERE clause or the ORDER BY clause. You will never be able to create an index that supports both, so make your choice.
Let's take the second query as an example.
To index the WHERE condition, the ideal indexes would be
CREATE INDEX ON _transfers (_from, blocknumber);
CREATE INDEX ON _transfers (_to, blocknumber);

To index the ORDER BY clause, you need
CREATE INDEX ON _transfers (blocknumber DESC, transactionindex);


Hi, but CREATE INDEX ON _transfers (blocknumber, transactionindex); I have already added and it does not help.

Sorry, I didn't see that one column was sorted descending. I have fixed the answer.

If you upgrade to version 13 or higher, then your existing index would probably work fine. That is because the incremental sorting feature was added in that version. With this feature, it can read using the index (backwards) to get things already in order of blockNumber DESC, and then just needs to sort within ties of blockNumber, rather than the entire dataset, and can stop early.
You can instead build the directional multi-column index already recommended by others, but v12 is approaching EOL so you should really be upgrading soon anyway...
